# Inserting data into MySql table using python Petl module showing error

Tags: python, mysql, etl

- Hi I am using `Petl` python module to perform ETL operations.
- While I am trying to insert data into MySQL table it shows
  (`Parameters for query must be list or tuple`) error.

Here is the sample code of what I tried,

```
from petl import todb

import mysql.connector

try:
    table = [['foo', 'bar'], ['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 2]]
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='10.100.0.000',database='test',user='root',password='123')
    connection.cursor().execute('SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES')
    todb(table, connection, 'petlTest')

except Exception, exception:
    print exception
```

Note : Table petlTest was created already with columns foo and bar.

Comment: Can you provide full traceback ?

Comment: @vovaminiof 
    todb(table, connection, 'petlTest')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\petl\io\db.py", line 337, in todb
    truncate=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\petl\io\db.py", line 356, in _todb
    commit=commit, truncate=truncate)
    cursor.executemany(insertquery, it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 599, in e
xecutemany
    "Parameters for query must be list or tuple.")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Parameters for query must be list or tu
ple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the `mysql.connector` to `mysql-python` module.

Answer (score -1):

First drop the table "petlTest"

```
drop TABLE petlTest
```

Comment: I tried it already but it shows  table not found error,........mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table test.petltest' doesn't exist